# Differences between Fjällräven's men and women backpacks

Tags: backpacks

I'm looking for a Keb 52 backpack but can only find the women's model where I am (and I'm a 190cm-tall man). Here are the specs for the men's and women's models on Fjällräven's website:

- Men model: https://www.fjallraven.com/fjallraven-mens-keb-52-black-black-f27342/
- Women model: https://www.fjallraven.com/fjallraven-womens-keb-52-w-lava-dark-lava-f27344/

What is the actual difference between the two models? Could the difference be so minimal that such a backpack, once the straps are adjusted, would fit nicely anyway?